# create spacing command that eliminates extra spaces after

Tags: spacing, sectioning, environments, lengths

After a `\section` command, there is the same amount of space regardless of what follows. An `itemize` environment does not add extra space.

How can I achieve the same behavior after a custom environment?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\postinfoskip}
\setlength{\postinfoskip}{2ex}

\newenvironment{info}
  {\itshape}
  {\vspace{\postinfoskip}}

\begin{document}
\section{The spacing after this section \dots}
This is a line of text that begins with a normal amount of space after the section heading.

\section{\dots{} is the same as the spacing after this one}
\begin{itemize}
\item First line of text
\item Second line of text
\end{itemize}

\section{But when I use a custom environment \dots}
\begin{info}
See how much space there is after this environment before normal text.
\end{info}

This is a line of text that begins with a normal amount of space after the environment.

\section{\dots{} I can't get consistent spacing after}
\begin{info}
Compare to the amount of space before itemize.
\end{info}

\begin{itemize}
\item First line of text starts after a gap
\item Second line of text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case I'd suggest using `\addvspace` rather than `\vspace`:

```
\newlength{\postinfoskip}
\setlength{\postinfoskip}{2ex}
\newenvironment{info}
  {\itshape}
  {\par\addvspace{\postinfoskip}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was reading the `latex.ltx` and `article.cls` source to try to figure out `\addvspace` but I couldn't see why it behaves this way. Could you explain?

Comment: @AndrewCashner: It adds *up to* the amount specified, [regardless of where it's placed in vertical mode](http://pastebin.com/ac6ewgfr).